# Trying to install/startup Jenkins in Ubuntu Server - hudson.util.AWTProblem

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to install/startup `Jenkins` (*2.303*) in Ubuntu, but now for **Server** (for **Desktop** there is no problem)

`JAVA_HOME` and `JENKINS_HOME` environment variables defined on the `.profile` file

About Java info:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 11.0.11

which java
/home/user/something/java/openjdk/jdk-11.0.11+9/bin/java
```

But for the first execution to startup Jenkins, happens the following

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
Running from: /home/user/something/jenkins/bin/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2021-07-22 18:15:09.003+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @1892ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2021-07-22 18:15:09.374+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2021-07-22 18:15:09.474+0000 [id=1]     WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2021-07-22 18:15:09.782+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.42.v20210604; built: 2021-06-04T17:33:38.939Z; git: 5cd5e6d2375eeab146813b0de9f19eda6ab6e6cb; jvm 11.0.11+9
2021-07-22 18:15:11.116+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2021-07-22 18:15:11.278+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2021-07-22 18:15:11.281+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2021-07-22 18:15:11.284+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2021-07-22 18:15:12.762+0000 [id=1]     INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /home/user/something/jenkins/contents found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2021-07-22 18:15:13.025+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  hudson.util.BootFailure#publish: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:379)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:324)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:84)
Caused: java.lang.InternalError
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:497)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1410)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily_NoClientCode(Font.java:1384)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1376)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.toString(Font.java:1869)
        at hudson.util.ChartUtil.<clinit>(ChartUtil.java:270)
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:251)
Caused: hudson.util.AWTProblem
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1068)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:997)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:192)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/home/user/something/jenkins/contents/war/WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-07-22 18:15:13.834+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@27d57a2c{Jenkins v2.303,/,file:///home/user/something/jenkins/contents/war/,AVAILABLE}{/home/user/something/jenkins/contents/war}
2021-07-22 18:15:13.893+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@4c178a76{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9090}
2021-07-22 18:15:13.893+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @6790ms
2021-07-22 18:15:13.897+0000 [id=22]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
```

Through a secondary PC with a web browser the configuration should be possible, it because the server version does not have GUI - anyway Jenkins started with that error message - is possible use `http://192.168.1.XX:9090` in a web browser - so Jenkins renders (in some way) the following message:

```
Error
AWT is not properly configured on this server. 
Perhaps you need to run your container with "-Djava.awt.headless=true"? 
See also: https://www.jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/java.awt.headless

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:379)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:324)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:84)
Caused: java.lang.InternalError
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:497)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1410)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily_NoClientCode(Font.java:1384)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1376)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.toString(Font.java:1869)
    at hudson.util.ChartUtil.<clinit>(ChartUtil.java:270)
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:192)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at Main._main(Main.java:375)
    at Main.main(Main.java:151)
```

So executing now using **Djava.awt.headless=true**

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
Running from: /home/user/something/jenkins/bin/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2021-07-22 18:30:37.797+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @2214ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2021-07-22 18:30:38.160+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2021-07-22 18:30:38.231+0000 [id=1]     WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2021-07-22 18:30:38.477+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.42.v20210604; built: 2021-06-04T17:33:38.939Z; git: 5cd5e6d2375eeab146813b0de9f19eda6ab6e6cb; jvm 11.0.11+9
2021-07-22 18:30:39.776+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2021-07-22 18:30:39.949+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2021-07-22 18:30:39.953+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2021-07-22 18:30:39.956+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2021-07-22 18:30:41.569+0000 [id=1]     INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /home/user/something/jenkins/contents found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2021-07-22 18:30:41.840+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  hudson.util.BootFailure#publish: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:379)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:324)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:84)
Caused: java.lang.InternalError
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:497)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1410)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily_NoClientCode(Font.java:1384)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1376)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.toString(Font.java:1869)
        at hudson.util.ChartUtil.<clinit>(ChartUtil.java:270)
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:251)
Caused: hudson.util.AWTProblem
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1068)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:997)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:192)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/home/user/something/jenkins/contents/war/WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-07-22 18:30:42.721+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@27d57a2c{Jenkins v2.303,/,file:///home/user/something/jenkins/contents/war/,AVAILABLE}{/home/user/something/jenkins/contents/war}
2021-07-22 18:30:42.781+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@b2c9a9c{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9090}
2021-07-22 18:30:42.785+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @7204ms
2021-07-22 18:30:42.789+0000 [id=22]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
```

How resolve this?

### More

According with the 3rd output there is available/suggested the following link for more details

- `https://www.jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/java.awt.headless`

Which it targets to:

- [Jenkins got java.awt.headless problem](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+got+java.awt.headless+problem)

it indicates to install (for my case)

- `sudo apt install ttf-dejavu`
- `sudo apt install xvfb`

It does **not** work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the following link at Jenkins Jira

- [AWT initialized even with -Djava.awt.headless=true](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-59396)

Is mandatory install `fontconfig[.x86_64]`, so was just enough execute

- `sudo apt install fontconfig`

**Note** in jira was really suggested to install `fontconfig.x86_64` but it does not exist on Ubuntu repositories. Perhaps is available for other distributions. So one of them should be viable, either `fontconfig` or `fontconfig.x86_64`

Once installed execute in peace:

- `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090` (is not need it *-Djava.awt.headless=true* )